# The nested serializer of extended group model is missing some fields in the user serializer

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I extended the Group model in my models.py and created the corresponding serializer, which is working fine. However, when I try to serialize the group field inside the User serializer I only obtain the default fields.
Let me show some part of the code:

*models.py*

```
class GroupExtended(Group):
    description =  models.TextField(blank=True)
    digitaltwin_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
        to = DigitaltwinPermission,
        blank = True,
        default = None,
        related_name = "gemelo"
    )
    panel_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
        to = PanelPermission,
        blank = True,
        default = None,
        related_name = "panel"
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "4. Grupos"
```

*serializer.py*

```
class GroupExtendedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    digitaltwin_permissions = DTPSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    panel_permissions = PPSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = GroupExtended
        fields = ['id','name','description','digitaltwin_permissions','panel_permissions','permissions']

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    groups = GroupExtendedSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

What I obtain with the user API is the following JSON:

```
{
"id":1,
"groups":[
   {"id":2,
    "name":"Admin",
    "permissions":[]}
],
etc
}
```

Instead, I would like to obtain:

```
{
"id":1,
"groups":[
   {"id":2,
    "name":"Admin",
    "permissions":[],
    "description": "whatever",
    "digitaltwin_permissions":[*serialized fields*],
    "panel_permissions": [*serialized fields*]
}
],
etc
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible?

Thank you!

Comment: In your models.py, don't you want null=True instead of  blank=True ?

Comment: I think it doesn't matter for me and doesn't affect the serializer.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing overwriting the *groups* field in the *User* class. Then, I had to change the User serializer as I wanted to write the groups with the ids (group_ids). In the end, the code is:

*models.py*

```
class GroupExtended(Group):
    description =  models.TextField(blank=True)
    digitaltwin_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
        to = DigitaltwinPermission,
        blank = True,
        default = None,
        related_name = "gemelo"
    )
    panel_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
        to = PanelPermission,
        blank = True,
        default = None,
        related_name = "panel"
    )

class User(AbstractUser):
    avatar = models.ForeignKey(
        Avatar, 
        on_delete = models.CASCADE,
        blank = True,
        null = True
    )

    groups = models.ManyToManyField(
        to = GroupExtended,
        blank = True
    )
```

And

*serializers.py*

```
class GroupExtendedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    digitaltwin_permissions = DTPSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    digitaltwin_permissions_ids = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True,  
        read_only=False, 
        queryset = DigitaltwinPermission.objects.all(),
        source = 'digitaltwin_permissions'
    )
    panel_permissions = PPSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    panel_permissions_ids = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True,  
        read_only=False, 
        queryset = PanelPermission.objects.all(),
        source = 'panel_permissions'
    )
    class Meta:
        model = GroupExtended
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 8

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    avatar = AvatarSerializer(read_only=True)
    avatar_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    groups = GroupExtendedSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    groups_ids = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True,  
        read_only=False, 
        queryset = GroupExtended.objects.all(),
        source = 'groups'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```